# Python: How to update dictionary with step-index from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I am a week-old python learner. I would like to know: Let’s say:

`list= [“a”, “A”, “b”, “B”, “c”, “C”]`

I need to update them in dictionary to be a result like this:

`dict={“a”:”A”, “b”:”B”, “c”:”C”}`

I try to use index of list within `dict.update({list[n::2]: list[n+1::2]}` and `for n in range(0,(len(list)/2))`

I think i did something wrong. Please correct me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don’t name variables `list` or `dict`. What IDE are you using, that wouldn’t point that out?

Comment: Sublime. BTW, my knowledge how to use python is limited. I only know format of result I need but don't know how to get the result lol.

Comment: Well then, time to hit the books ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C']
>>> dct = dict(zip(lst[::2],lst[1::2]))
>>> dct
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}
```

**Explanation**:

```
>>> lst[::2]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> lst[1::2]
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])
# this actually gives a zip iterator which contains:
# [('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')]
>>> dict(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
# here each tuple is interpreted as key value pair, so finally you get:
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}
```

**NOTE**: Don't name your variables same as python keywords.

Correct version of your program would be:

```
lst = ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C']
dct = {}
for n in range(0,int(len(lst)/2)):
  dct.update({lst[n]: lst[n+1]})
print(dct)
```

Yours did not work because you used slices in each iteration, instead of accessing each individual element. `lst[0::2]` gives `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `lst[1::2]` gives `['A', 'B', 'C']`. So for the first iteration, when `n == 0` you are trying to update the dictionary with the pair `['a', 'b', 'c'] : ['A', 'B', 'C']` and you will get a type error as `list` can not be assigned as key to the dictionary as `list`s are unhashable.

Comment: Thank you. Yours did work. But mine got error ```IndentationError: expected at indented block``` at ```dct.update({lst[n]: lst[n+1]})```

Comment: Just remove the leading space, and hit tab for that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension like this:

```
>>> l = list("aAbBcCdD")
>>> l
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D']
>>> { l[i] : l[i+1] for i in range(0,len(l),2)}
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C', 'd': 'D'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code would be the perfect apt to your question. Hope this helped you

```
a = ["a", "A", "B","b", "c","C","d", "D"]
b = {}
for each in range(len(a)):
    if each % 2 == 0:
        b[a[each]] = a[each + 1]
print(b)
```